# Why does my query does not work in Visual studio 2010 report builder

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I want to submit a new report under an existing folder/project.

Query for the new report is as followed:

```
select o.companycode, o.name, w.StartTravelTime, w.DateAndTimeStart, w.DateAndTimeEnd, w.InspectionID , w.Longitude as 'GPSLongitude', w.Latitude as 'GPSLongitude', o.Longitude, o.Latitude, ACOS(SIN(PI()*w.Latitude/180.0)*SIN(PI()*o.Latitude/180.0)+COS(PI()*w.Latitude/180.0)*COS(PI()*o.Latitude/180.0)*COS(PI()*o.Longitude/180.0-PI()*w.Longitude/180.0))*6371 as 'Afwijking in km'
from Anticimex_WorkRecords w,
     CRM_Organisations o,
     Anticimex_Inspections i,
     Users u
where w.InspectionID = i.id
and i.BrancheOrganisationID = o.id
and u.id = w.userid
and w.DateAndTimeStart between @Param3 and @Param4
and u.username = @Param5
```

If I want to continue I get the following error: 'an error occurred while the query design method was being saved. An item with the same key has already been added.'

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above query is product specific.)

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: sql server management studio. Query works fine if I run it there.

Comment: SSMS is a management tool, not a data base. This means you're using SQL Server. The error complains about the report though, not the query

Comment: I would remove the dataset and start again. It sounds like you are trying to add a field to the data sets' field definitions but that field has already been defined.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello with some tips and after recreating the report I finally succeeded. Can I close this question/thread?

Answer (score 1):

```
..., w.Longitude as 'GPSLongitude', w.Latitude as 'GPSLongitude',...
```

^ Pretty sure I found your duplicate. Typos like this would be easier to spot if you used carriage returns to make your queries more readable.

Other notes:

- please don't use `'` to delimit column or table aliases; this makes them look like string literals (and the syntax is deprecated in some forms). If you need to escape poor naming choices use `[square brackets]`. (More on aliases [here](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases).)
- please [always specify the schema](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix) for each object
- please don't use [1980s-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)